# Finding IDs that join with multiple alternate IDs matching criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm guessing there is a quick and easy solution to this but I've tried a number of different methods and keep hitting a stone wall. Tried searching a LOT both here and elsewhere but I don't think I am using the right words to clarify what I want to know (as per my confusing subject!). My apologies if this is a duplicate or similar.

So, to explain the problem (obfuscated as the actual data is somewhat sensitive), say you have a table of clients, a table of meetings that you have with those clients (the meetings may have multiple clients tied to each), and another table with fees charged to these clients during the meetings. There may be single or multiple fees charged at a single meeting (i.e. consulting fee, new contract fee, purchasing fee, etc.).

What I'm trying to find is any instances where the system may have erroneously charged multiple copies of the same type of fee to a client, i.e. a consulting fee that can only ever be charged once per meeting.

The way this would be identified is by finding fees of that type (let's say CONS for consulting) and then checking if there are multiple distinct **fee_id**s of that type tied to a single **meeting_id**. It is possible that you might have 10 rows for the same **fee_type** within the same meeting (say, for 10 clients attending the same meeting) but they should all be tied to the same **fee_id**.

The solutions I've tried seem to either count these as 10 entries (where it should just count them as one) or counts rows individually and doesn't group them all in to the same meeting, etc.

Here's a simple, rough example of what it'd look like (though this is wrong, as it doesn't group the distinct counting within unique **meeting_id**s):

```
select c.client_name as "Client"
    , m.meeting_id as "Meeting ID"
    , m.meeting_date as "Meeting Date"
    , f.fee_type as "Fee Type"
    , count(distinct 
        (
            case when f.fee_type = 'CONS'
            then f.fee_id 
            else null 
            end
        )
    ) as "Consultation Fees Charged"
from client c
inner join meetings m
    on c.client_id = m.client_id
inner join fees f
    on m.meeting_id = f.meeting_id
where f.fee_type = ‘CONS’
group by c.client_name, m.meeting_id, m.meeting_date
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution and I'm just missing something obvious. Sorry for the mass of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% that I understand what you are looking for.  I think it is fees of a certain type applied to a particular meeting for a particular client.  If so, your basic query is on the right track, but it needs a `group by` and some simplification in the `case` (the `case` is redundant with the `where`):

```
select c.client_name as "Client", m.meeting_id as "Meeting ID", m.meeting_date as "Meeting Date",
       count(distinct f.fee_id ) as "Consultation Fees Charged"
from client c inner join
     meetings m
     on c.client_id = m.client_id inner join
     fees f
     on m.meeting_id = f.meeting_id
where f.fee_type = 'CONS'
group by c.client_name, m.meeting_id, m.meeting_date
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the instances where the system may have erroneously charged multiple copies of the same type of fee to a client, we can use `GROUP BY` and then check total clients in the meeting and total fee_ids per meeting are matching using `HAVING` clause.

The below query will return all such meetings, where there is discrepancy for `consultation fees`

```
SELECT m.meeting_id as "Meeting ID", 
       m.meeting_date as "Meeting Date",
       count(f.fee_id ) as "Total Fee record count",
       count(c.client_name) as "Total Client count"
FROM client c 
INNER JOIN  meetings m
ON c.client_id = m.client_id 
INNER JOIN fees f
on m.meeting_id = f.meeting_id
AND f.fee_type = 'CONS'
group by c.client_name, m.meeting_id, m.meeting_date
having count(f.fee_id) <> count(c.client_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the duplicate fees charged by finding the difference between no of clients and no of fees charged .IF it is zero then no duplicate fees else the no of duplicate fees charged

```
 select count(distinct c.client_name) as "Client",
   m.meeting_id as "Meeting ID",
   m.meeting_date as "Meeting Date",
   f.fee_type as "Fee Type",
   count(distinct f.fee_id) as "Consultation Fees Charged",
   (count(distinct f.fee_id) - count(distinct c.client_name)) as "Duplicate fee charged"
      from client c
      inner join meetings m on c.client_id = m.client_id
      inner join fees f on m.meeting_id = f.meeting_id
      where f.fee_type = ‘CONS’
      group by m.meeting_id, m.meeting_date, f.fee_type
```